# Estimate Poisson parameter

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, poisson-distribution, maximum-likelihood

**1. Background:**

Given a parameter $k\in\mathbb{R}^+$.

I have a bunch of positive data pairs $\{(a_i,b_i)|a_i\in\mathbb{R}^+, b_i\in\mathbb{R}^+\}_{i=1}^N$.

For each pair $(a_i,b_i)$, an observation value $y_i$ is generated by:

$$
y_i=\frac{1}{k}(A_i-B_i),~~~~A_i\sim \text{Pois}(ka_i),~~~~B_i\sim \text{Pois}(kb_i),
$$

where $A_i$ and $B_i$ are independent.

In other words, each $y_i$ is generated by the following three steps:

$(1.1)$ Get $a_i$ and randomly pick a value for $A_i$ from $\text{Pois}(ka_i)$.

$(1.2)$ Get $b_i$ and randomly pick a value for $B_i$ from $\text{Pois}(kb_i)$.

$(1.3)$ Perform $y_i=\frac{1}{k}(A_i-B_i)$.

---

**2. My Question:**

Now I have a bunch of data points and observation values $\{(a_i,b_i,y_i)\}_{i=1}^N$.

How can I estimate the unknown latent parameter $k\in\mathbb{R}^+$ (globally unified)?

---

**3. My Efforts:**

$(3.1)$ I may know that the expected value and variance of each $y_i$ can be calculated by:

\begin{align}
E(y_i)&=\frac{1}{k}[E(A_i)-E(B_i)]=\frac{1}{k}(ka_i-kb_i)=a_i-b_i,\\
D(y_i)&=\frac{1}{k^2}[D(A_i)+D(B_i)]=\frac{1}{k^2}(ka_i+kb_i)=\frac{1}{k}(a_i+b_i).
\end{align}

$(3.2)$ There are actually $N$ independent nested distributions. For the $i$-th observation, I can not calculate the variance (since there is only one observation $y_i$) to perform maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) or moment estimation (ME) with using $D(y_i)=\frac{1}{k}(a_i+b_i)$.

$(3.3)$ I am confused by how to find a best $k$ that can fit the data points and observations well, by starting from some convincing ideas like MLE or ME?

$(3.4)$ Since there may be actually not only one distribution, but exist $N$ compounded distributions, and each compounded distribution correspond to only one data point and observation $(a_i,b_i,y_i)$, I have no idea about finding the best $k$.

---

**4. Update (1):**

I start from the idea of maximum likelihood estimation (MLE).

First, let $Y_i$ be a random variable corresponding to $y_i$, then I have:

\begin{align}
P(Y_i=s)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(A_i=n+ks)P(B_i=n)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(ka_i)^{n+ks}e^{-ka_i}}{(n+ks)!}\times \frac{(kb_i)^{n}e^{-kb_i}}{n!}\\
&=(ka_i)^{ks}e^{-k(a_i+b_i)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(k^2a_ib_i)^n}{n!(n+ks)!}.
\end{align}

From [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BDivide%5BPower%5Bx%2Cn%5D%2C%5C%2840%29n%21%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29n%2Bks%5C%2841%29%21%5D%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D), I have:

\begin{align}
P(Y_i=s)&=(ka_i)^{ks}e^{-k(a_i+b_i)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(k^2a_ib_i)^n}{n!(n+ks)!}\\
&=(ka_i)^{ks}e^{-k(a_i+b_i)} (k^2a_ib_i)^{-\frac{ks}{2}}I_{ks}(2k\sqrt{a_ib_i})\\
&=(\frac{a_i}{b_i})^{\frac{ks}{2}}e^{-k(a_i+b_i)}I_{ks}(2k\sqrt{a_ib_i}),
\end{align}

where $I_{ks}(\cdot)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind.

Using the idea of MLE, I want to solve the following problem:

\begin{align}
\hat{k}&=\underset{k}{\arg\max}~\prod_{i=1}^N{P(Y_i=y_i|k)}\\
&=\underset{k}{\arg\max}~\sum_{i=1}^N{lnP(Y_i=y_i|k)}\\
&=\underset{k}{\arg\max}~\sum_{i=1}^N{ln\left[(\frac{a_i}{b_i})^{\frac{ky_i}{2}}e^{-k(a_i+b_i)}I_{ky_i}(2k\sqrt{a_ib_i})\right]}\\
&=\underset{k}{\arg\max}~\sum_{i=1}^N{\frac{ky_i}{2}ln(\frac{a_i}{b_i})-k(a_i+b_i)+ln\left[I_{ky_i}(2k\sqrt{a_ib_i})\right]}\\
&=\underset{k}{\arg\max}~\sum_{i=1}^N{k\left[\frac{y_i}{2}ln(\frac{a_i}{b_i})-(a_i+b_i)\right]+ln\left[I_{ky_i}(2k\sqrt{a_ib_i})\right]}.
\end{align}

Due to the existence of $ln\left[I_{ky_i}(2k\sqrt{a_ib_i})\right]$, I am stucked and think that it is too hard for me to get the derivative and the optimal $k$.

The derivative of the above infinite series is also quite complicated: [Link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=D%5Bln%5C%2840%29Sum%5BDivide%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29Power%5Bk%2C2%5Dt%5C%2841%29%2Cn%5D%2C%5C%2840%29n%21%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29n%2Bks%5C%2841%29%21%5D%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D%5C%2841%29%2Ck%5D).

After a long struggle, I am still failed to get the answer.

I am not sure if the above steps are all correct.

Could you please figure it out for me?

---

**5. Update (2):**

Following the suggestion from @BinxuWang王彬旭, I write the following Python program for simulation:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import skellam

data_len = 80
max_value = 1.0
A = np.random.rand(data_len,) * max_value 
B = np.random.rand(data_len,) * max_value 
k_gt = 100.0

Y_observed = (np.random.poisson(k_gt * A) - np.random.poisson(k_gt * B)) / k_gt

for k in range(9):
    k = 10 ** (k - 4)
    Y_k = Y_observed * k
    mu1 = A * k
    mu2 = B * k
    L = np.sum(np.log(skellam._pmf(Y_k, mu1, mu2)))  # L = sum(log(...))
    print(k, L)
```

The output is:

```
0.0001 -0.031569807095909126
0.001 -0.2549938771522239
0.01 -1.9421743846032573
0.1 -13.274040574073975
1 -66.80138745123028
10 -162.06597061912214
100 -278.81300414250535
1000 nan
10000 nan
```

The true value of $k$ is $100$.

However, I see that the optimal $k$ given by this program will always be zero, since the likelihood evaluation value may monotonically decrease in $(0,+\infty)$. And even when $k=100$, I can not see that it peaks the maximal value.

Similar phenomenons are observed with various combinations of `data_len`, `max_value` and `k_gt`.

Is my implementation wrong, or I missed something?

---

**6. Update (3):**

It seems that the following approach inspired by a comment from [Zhihu](https://www.zhihu.com/question/535210244) works.

[image]

Let $Z_i=\frac{Y_i-(a_i-b_i)}{\sqrt{a_i+b_i}}$, then we have $E(Z_i)=0$ and $D(Z_i)=\frac{1}{k}$.

Although different $Z_i$s might not obey the same latent population distribution, I write the following program for test:

```
import numpy as np

data_len = 1000000
max_value = 1e3

for i in range(10):
    k_gt = np.random.rand(1,) * 1e4

    A = np.random.rand(data_len,) * max_value 
    B = np.random.rand(data_len,) * max_value 

    Y_observed = (np.random.poisson(k_gt * A) - np.random.poisson(k_gt * B)) / k_gt

    z = (Y_observed - (A - B)) / ((A + B) ** 0.5)
    k_hat = 1 / z.var()
    #print('E(z) =', z.mean())
    #print('D(z) =', z.var())
    print('True k =', k_gt)
    print('Estimated k = ', k_hat)
    print('===')
```

The output is:

```
True k = [2298.1854775]
Estimated k =  2300.5718461385372
===
True k = [7922.65659395]
Estimated k =  7917.124293172064
===
True k = [263.85265814]
Estimated k =  263.6420801776157
===
True k = [6645.19567678]
Estimated k =  6648.825624909179
===
True k = [9224.97551002]
Estimated k =  9221.90494158757
===
True k = [5343.45415427]
Estimated k =  5343.7859362020945
===
True k = [3711.94735707]
Estimated k =  3722.572332730343
===
True k = [5075.17847329]
Estimated k =  5071.739140612038
===
True k = [4805.75795587]
Estimated k =  4806.967854078318
===
True k = [1378.56419652]
Estimated k =  1379.657342920305
===
```

I think this method may be sensible since it gives estimation $\hat{k}$ quite close to the latent true $k$. And when the sample number `data_len` increases, the estimation becomes more accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we'd like to use MLE, we need to evaluate the probability of $y_i$ given $a_i$ $b_i$ and $k$, i.e. have a probabilistic generative model of $y_i$. So here is a brute force numerical way to do so.

The difference of two Poisson variables is distributed as [Skellam_distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution).
The two parameters of Skellam distr. are $\mu_1=ka_i$ and $\mu_2=kb_i$, and the observed value is $ky_i$. Then we could insert these three numbers into a [package evaluating the pmf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skellam.html) of the Skellam distribution
$$
\mathcal L(k|\{a_i,b_i,y_i\})=\prod_i P_{skellam}(ky_i;ka_i,kb_i)
$$
Then we could try optimizing $\mathcal L(k)$ using numerical optimization routines.

The hard part of this optimization is that $ky_i$ needs to be an integer to have a non-zero probability mass. otherwise, the likelihood vanishes. **So, this is actually a discrete optimization problem, not amenable to gradient descent.**

One way to tackle this is we propose a set of feasible solutions $K=\{k|ky_i\in\mathbb Z,\forall i\}$. This will be an infinite set, since $k\in K\Rightarrow nk\in K,\forall n\in\mathbb Z$.

We may perform gradient-like optimization (local search / hill climbing) in this set...

---

An update, actually the analytical form of likelihood (below) is continuous to $ky_i$ (non-integer).

I checked [the implementation of PMF](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/4cf21e753cf937d1c6c2d2a0e372fbc1dbbeea81/scipy/stats/_discrete_distns.py#L1348) in the `scipy`, actually we can evaluate the likelihood formula anywhere without $ky_i$ being an integer.

The vanishing `pmf` at non integer value is enforced by the code, not the math. We just need to use `skellam._pmf` instead of `skellam.pmf` to circumvent the integer check by `scipy`.

In this way, we could do numerical optimization on this smoother landscape. Though the distribution makes sense only when $ky_i$ are integers.

```
from scipy.stats import skellam
In [23]: skellam.pmf(0.0,2,2)
Out[23]: 0.20700192122398667
In [24]: skellam._pmf(0.0,2,2)
Out[24]: array(0.20700192)
In [25]: skellam.pmf(0.1,2,2)
Out[25]: 0.0
In [26]: skellam._pmf(0.1,2,2)
Out[26]: array(0.20667417)
```

---

Analytically, the PMF of Skellam distr. is
$$
p(n;\mu_1,\mu_2)=\exp(-(\mu_1+\mu_2))(\frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2})^{n/2} I_{|n|}(2\sqrt{\mu_1\mu_2})
$$
With $I_{|n|}$ the Bessel function.
$$
P(ky_i;ka_i,kb_i)=\exp(k(a_i+b_i))(\frac{a_i}{b_i})^{\frac {ky_i} {2}}I_{|ky_i|}(2\sqrt{k^2a_ib_i})
$$

Comment: Thanks. Can I substitute $(ky_i)$ with $\left[\text{round}(ky_i)\right]$ to get an approximated result, with enabling $k$ to be continuous values in $\mathbb{R}^+$ for easier implementation?

Comment: Numerically, that definitely worth a try! I feel the landscape could be smoother

Comment: I updated the answer, so it seems we don't even need `round`, with a tweak in the code we could evaluate likelihood anywhere

Comment: Hi @Binxu Wang 王彬旭, I write a tiny program for test (please see the above **5. Update (2)**). But it seems that I am still failed to find the latent best $k$. Do I make some mistakes?

Comment: @BinChen Yeah your program looks great, if I were to write program I shall do something very similar to you.... I'm thinking

Comment: Hi @Binxu Wang 王彬旭, I get an inspiration from https://www.zhihu.com/question/535210244 and write a new toy program (please see above **6. Update (3)**). It seems that it may works.

Comment: Looks very promising! Could MLE be a flawed inference procedure in this case?